# frigidaire freezer ffu14f5hwf not freezing

Tags: appliances

Hello was hoping to get some help. My 4 year old freezer only gets down to 20 degrees. So ice and ice pops will not freeze. I changed the defrost thermostat . It was a used unit and when I opened the back I noticed the fan would not stop running and also the defrost thermostat was not connected to anything but itself. So whoever tried to repair it obviously didnt know what they where doing. Now with new thermostat installed I noticed the fan shuts off but temperature gets up to 30 degrees.

Comment: ice is already frozen ... do you mean that water won't freeze? ... 20 degrees is certainly cold enough to freeze water

Comment: In the future, you may want to _unplug_ the freezer _before_ opening it up and messing with the wiring - you could injure or killing yourself messing with appliances that are plugged in. Was the "defrost thermostat" a used unit, or was the fridge itself a "used unit"? Is that 20°F or 20°C? Water will freeze at 20°F, but not so much at 20°C. Have you searched the internet for a wiring diagram for your freezer and use that to fix the wiring on the defrost thermostat? Have you considered that the _defrost_ thermostat may not be the problem but it may be the _main_ thermostat?

Comment: Or... it has lost much of its freon and the previous owner ASSumed that the problem was the defrost thermostat, so he disconnected it. Then when that didn't fix it, he sold it to you...

Comment: Hi thank you for the comments. I received the freezer when I bought my house it worked for a while temp was getting down to 0. I meant water does not freeze and also ice pops are not solid. It is actually 20 farenheit.  I definitely unplug things before I worked on ,what I actually meant was every time I'm near it the fan is on. Since changing the defrost thermostat I noticed the fan turned off, I guess it went into defrost mode. How would I know if the thermostat is no good? The light on outside of unit is lit up and it turns off when I put it to zero.